# Algorithm to find optimal bounding volume for point cloud

Tags: computational-geometry, point-clouds, bounding-volume

For a point cloud do there exist algorithms to tell the bounding volume that bounds the points in the most compact way, or in a way that minimizes the empty spaces inside the bounding volume? Examples of the bounding volumes in question are bounding boxes, spheres, cylinders and capsules.

Comment: Perhaps a variant of RanSaC? [RanSaC tutorial with the PCL library](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/random_sample_consensus.html)

Comment: @Stef Would this algorithm help identify the closest shape that point cloud resembles like a sphere or a box from identifying "inliers"?

Comment: Yes, ransac can help you find the "best-fitting sphere" (or some other shape of your choice). That shape will not necessarily enclose all the points. The non-enclosed points will be called "outliers" and the enclosed points will be closed "inliers". If you want to enclose all the points then perhaps Ransac is not the right tool.

Comment: @Stef I don't necessarily need to enclose all points so this could work thank you!

Comment: Actually, Ransac was the first thing I thought of when I read your question, but after thinking a bit more I'm not completely convinced. Note that the library I linked uses the mathematical definition for "sphere". I.e., a sphere is just a surface, not a volume. So it won't try to "enclose some points inside the sphere" but rather "fit some points on the surface of the sphere"; points which are outside and points which are inside will both be considered outliers, and only points on the surface (or close to the surface) will be considered inliers.

Comment: Wikipedia lists some algorithms to find a minimum-volume [bounding sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere), but these algorithms include all points, without leaving outliers.

Comment: @Stef The point clouds are actually generated from meshes which are shallow surfaces, so I think Ransac might still work...

Comment: Not enclosing all points and finding the minimum volume are conflicting goals. You need to specify more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is trivial for the axis-aligned boxes.

For arbitrary boxes, I guess that a generalization of rotating calipers is possible (compute the convex hull and try all orientations defined by a plane that contains a face and another plane containing an edge).

For spheres, use the Welzl algorithm.

For a cylindre or a capsule, mh, good luck...